# Select all rows in a table of certain type

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, compare, except

**I'm using SQL Server 2005 and need to write a select statement that selects all of the rows  within the table but only for columns of certain types.** In my case I want all columns except those of type xml, text, ntext, image, or nonbinary CLR user-defined type columns.

That is the question. If you want to know why I'm doing this read on. I'm using `EXCEPT` to identify differences between each table in two databases similar to what is outlined in this question: [SQL compare data from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602083/sql-compare-data-from-two-tables). I don't understand why `INTERSECT` was suggested in the comment so I'm using UNION ALL instead.

The code I'm using is:

```
(select *, 'table a first' as where_missing from A EXCEPT select *,'table a first' as where_missing from B)
union all
(select *,'table b first' as where_missing from B EXCEPT select *, 'table b first' as where_missing from A)
```

Some of the tables contain column types which don't work with `EXCEPT`. Therefore I don't want to select those columns. I can get this info from information_schema.columns but is there a nice way that I can then use that in my example above in place of the "*"?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide good Question or explanation. this is quite confusing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it other than using dynamic SQL. First select columns:

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max);
select @columns = stuff( 
    (select ', ' + c.name
    from sys.tables t
    join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
    join sys.types ty on c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    where t.name = 'A'
    and ty.name not in ('text', 'ntext', 'xml', 'image')
    for xml path(''))
, 1, 2, '');
```

Then run the query:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select ' + @columns + ', ''table a first'' as where_missing from A';
exec (@sql);
```

Comment: This did the trick. I used this to create a stored proc that takes two db names and a table name and returns all of the discrepancies.