# SQL query comparison between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in my database:

```
table_A:             table_B:                  

id    user           id    user               
1     Mike           1     Mike          
2     Dan            2     Dan           
3     Tom            3     Tom
4     Lina           4     Lina
                     5     Cynthia
                     6     Sam
```

My aim is to identify which users in Table_B do not exist in Table_A based on id. I'm new in SQL, and this is what i came up with:

```
SELECT id FROM Table_B
WHERE B.id NOT IN ( SELECT A.id from Table_A)
```

Most likely my logic is wrong, so i'd appreciate any guidance please.

Comment: This other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602083/sql-compare-data-from-two-tables) might be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-query in `WHERE` clause predicate `NOT IN` Then it will return the `id` present in `table_B` only

**Sub-Query**

This query return `id` from `table_A`

```
SELECT table_A.id FROM table_A
```

Then it will be passed to `NOT IN` clause which will return boolean `true` on every record set iteration if not matched. So `id` 5 and 6 only return in the main query.

**Final Query**

```
SELECT table_B.id, table_B.name FROM table_B WHERE table_B.id NOT IN (SELECT table_A.id FROM table_A);
```

OR

to select all column use symbol `*` instead of column lists

```
SELECT * FROM table_B WHERE table_B.id NOT IN (SELECT table_A.id FROM table_A);
```

Comment: if i want to extract the user also with the id do i do :
SELECT table_B.id AND  table_B.user FROM table_B WHERE table_B.id NOT IN (SELECT table_A.id FROM table_A);

Comment: @dan Learn using some good sql book before using mysql my suggestion goes to http://www.db-book.com/ or else you don't have time to read this book, then you can directly jump into mysql go for this book https://www.murach.com/shop/murach-s-mysql-detail a bit old but its easy and clear to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EXISTS** function.

```
Select * from table_B where Not EXISTS (select * from table_A)
```

Comment: but isn't the * a slow solution, when you want one element from a table?

Comment: Mysql run this query. More detail to refer this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

You are close. It seems to me that the only thing you need to change is the A.ID and B.ID reference

```
SELECT id FROM Table_B B
WHERE B.id NOT IN ( SELECT A.id from Table_A A)
```

Since you are referring to Table_A as A and table_B as B you need to create the alias name.

You could also use

```
SELECT id FROM Table_B B
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT A.id from Table_A A where A.ID = B.ID)
```

but i would prefer the first one.

Comment: I got token mismatch, what could be the problem?