# SQL Logic or Query to find what is missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, records

Hi all I need your help on the following logic.  Currently I have a table that has 300 records, that are related but on this new tables I have the columns called them country, POS so for each combination of country + POs I should have 1 record of table A.

but the situation is that when I am checking the last table someone only inserted some records of table A into table b, and now I have to find what are the missing combination.

could you guide me on the logic that I should use for this, any question please let me know.

```
Example

Table A name Categories
Milk
Hot Sauces
Meat

Table B
Category    POS    Country
Milk        DF      Mexico
Meat        DF      Mexico
Hot Sauces  DF      Mexico
Milk        CC      Canada
```

Like you can see Canada still missing 2 categories but this table have all Americas countries so let say I have 20 countries.  So 20 multiple by 300 categories I should have 6000  distinct records or more because each country have different quantities of POS, right, but someone only inserted let say 3600 records so now I have to find what combination are missed.

Comment: Let me put example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602083/sql-compare-data-from-two-tables

Comment: Thanks Flavor but still not answering my scenario, because Table a and table b on my question have differents amount of columns and records.

Comment: you need a cartisean join between distinct countries and categories then compare against that it is relatively easy just cross join but I am not following what the POS is and how it relates to your desired result.  Plus you really should show us what your desired result is!

Comment: also what RDBM? sql-sever, mysql, oracle?

Comment: MS SQL Server, I know what you mean but for me is complicated to express the idea.  POS is Point of Sales, let say that on country like USA you have a Walmart by each state or Mexico have a specific chain of store for each city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Don't have a country table you can derive one by selecting DISTINCT Country from your TableB.  Then cross join that with Categories for a Cartesian Join (all possible combinations) between Countries and Categories.

```
SELECT countries.country, c.Category
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Country
    FROM
       @TableB) as countries
    CROSS JOIN @Categories c
    LEFT JOIN @TableB b
    ON countries.Country = b.Country
    AND c.Category = b.Cateogry
WHERE
    b.Cateogry IS NULL
```

If you actually need All Possible Combinations of POS and Country and Categories.  In this case it sounds like POS is more like a store than a point of sale but same concept.  Just derive a POS table if you don't have one and cross join it with the cross join of countries and categories.

```
SELECT
    countries.country, c.Category, pos.POS
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Country
    FROM
       @TableB) as countries
    CROSS JOIN @Categories c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT POS
       FROM
          @TableB) as pos
    LEFT JOIN @TableB b
    ON countries.Country = b.Country
    AND c.Category = b.Cateogry
    AND pos.POS = b.POS
WHERE
    b.Cateogry IS NULL
```

But I would guess that not every store is in every country so you probably want to constrain the POS combiantions to POS's that are available in a particular country.  Again you can derive the table if you don't have one this time include Country and do an inner join between the derived country table and it.

```
SELECT
    countries.country, c.Category, pos.POS
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Country
    FROM
       @TableB) as countries
    CROSS JOIN @Categories c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Country, POS
       FROM
          @TableB) as pos
    ON countries.Country = pos.Country
    LEFT JOIN @TableB b
    ON countries.Country = b.Country
    AND c.Category = b.Cateogry
    AND pos.POS = b.POS
WHERE
    b.Cateogry IS NULL
```

test data used:

```
DECLARE @Categories AS TABLE (Category VARCHAR(25))
DECLARE @TableB AS TABLE (Cateogry VARCHAR(25),POS CHAR(2), Country VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @Categories VALUES ('Milk'),('Hot Sauces'),('Meat')
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES ('Milk','DF','Mexico'),('Meat','DF','Mexico'),('Hot Sauces','DF','Mexico'),('Milk','CC','Canada'),('Milk','XX','Canada')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 You can use below logic to get missing data,

```
SELECT column_name FROM tableA WHERE column_name NOT IN 
(SELECT column_name FROM tableB)
```

Change the required column names and table names in the query. Use same column names in all three places