# Compare columns between two MYSQL tables

Tags: mysql

To automate the backup process of the `Users` database, I would like to compare the structure of two tables (`Users` vs `ArchivedUsers`).

I want to compare the columns between both tables to make sure that the the same columns exist, i.e a column like `firebase_id` isn't added to the `Users` table without being added to the `ArchivedUsers` table as well.

A user on stackexchange, @RolandoMySQLDBA, put together a query that compares two tables in a database.

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(1)>0,'Differences','No Differences') Comparison FROM
(
    SELECT
        column_name,ordinal_position,
        data_type,column_type,COUNT(1) rowcount
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema=DATABASE()
    AND table_name IN ('users','archived_users')
    GROUP BY
        column_name,ordinal_position,
        data_type,column_type
    HAVING COUNT(1)=1
) A;
```

Can you think of a query that can compare the columns in two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way to do this, but for MySQL I suggest this:

```
SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
FROM
(
  SELECT 'Table A' as TableName, A.ID, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, ...
  FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Table B' as TableName, B.ID, B.COL1, B.COl2, B.COL3, ...
  FROM B
) tmp
GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

This query is sourced from a blog by Jeff Smith ([here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx))

The advantage of this approach is you get to know which table has the different row(s)

An earlier SO question on this topic is here which shows other methods particularly for DBMS platforms that support EXCEPT or MINUS at: 
[SQL compare data from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602083/sql-compare-data-from-two-tables)

Comment: Thank you @Used_By_Already for the run down, great read as well!

Comment: a pleasure to be sure. enjoy.