# Checking if contents of two table are identical in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have views in two databases V1 and V2 with same set of columns col1, col2.

Now I would like to know if they contains identical rows. In this context I have gone through this post: [SQL compare data from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602083/sql-compare-data-from-two-tables).

Following this I am running the below query:

```
  select * from v1.A
  minus
  select * from v2.A;
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from v2.A' at line 3
```

I am not getting any clue regarding how to fix this error.

Comment: *I would like to know if they contains identical rows* what does *identical* mean? How come 2 datasets that return the same number of rows be *identical*?

Comment: @forpas, I have a use case where I am running two experiments and dumping the data in two tables in two different databases with same schema.

Comment: Fine, but I'm sure that what you don't want is to consider identical 2 tables with the same number  of rows, right? My question was posted after you accepted the answer that did exactly that.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right. @forpas, I mistakenly accepted this. I realiized even if the values of a field differ in two tables, then also I am getting count1+count2=count3

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate `minus` which is not supported in MySql with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t1.* from v1.A t1
where not exists (
  select * from v2.A t2
  where t2.col1 <=> t1.col1 and t2.col2 <=> t1.col2
)
```

I use the *NULL-safe equal operator* [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) instead of just `=` just in case there are `null`s that need to be compared.
But if this query does not return any results it does not mean that the 2 views return the same rows, because `v1.A` may return a subset of the rows returned by `v1.B`.
So you also need:

```
select t2.* from v2.A t2
where not exists (
  select * from v1.A t1
  where t2.col1 <=> t1.col1 and t2.col2 <=> t1.col2
)
```

and maybe better a `UNION ALL` of the 2 queries to be sure:

```
select 1 from_view, t1.* from v1.A t1
where not exists (
  select * from v2.A t2
  where t2.col1 <=> t1.col1 and t2.col2 <=> t1.col2
)
union all
select 2 from_view, t2.* from v2.A t2
where not exists (
  select * from v1.A t1
  where t2.col1 <=> t1.col1 and t2.col2 <=> t1.col2
)
```