# How to compare two tables and if the values match, update one of the tables with the values from a third table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 3 tables, the `MAIN_TABLE`, the `SUB_TABLE` and the `ID_TABLE`.

I need to compare the `CODE` in the `MAIN_TABLE` with the `CODE` in the `SUB_TABLE`, and if they match, search for the `SUB_ID` in the `ID_TABLE` and update the `ID` in the `MAIN_TABLE` with that `ID`.

In the example shown below, the query should update the `MAIN_TABLE` with the `ID = 2071`.

`MAIN_TABLE`:

| CODE | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 0290380007800 | 994526 |

`SUB_TABLE`:

| CODE | SUB_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 029038078 | 106603 |

`ID_TABLE`:

| ID | SUB_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2071 | 106603 |

To match the code from the `MAIN_TABLE` with the code from the `SUB_TABLE`, I need to select it like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(CODE, 1, 6) + SUBSTRING(CODE, 9, 3) 
FROM 
    MAIN_TABLE
```

How can I achieve this?

Here's the dbfiddle with more data in each table: https://dbfiddle.uk/6H_mnPDR?hide=28

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602083/sql-how-to-compare-two-tables-for-same-data-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join your tables together as part of an update statement. Note this gives you duplicates, but then you already had duplicate IDs so I guess thats expected (although unusual).

```
UPDATE mt SET
    id = it.id
FROM MAIN_TABLE mt
INNER JOIN SUB_TABLE st ON st.code = SUBSTRING(mt.CODE, 1, 6) + SUBSTRING(mt.CODE, 9, 3) 
INNER JOIN ID_TABLE it ON it.SUB_ID = st.SUB_ID;
```

Comment: Clean and simple, thanks! And yes, the duplicate IDs are expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sub-query you can solve your problem. You can try below code:

```
update MAIN_TABLE set
    MAIN_TABLE.ID = Final.SUB_ID
from (
    select distinct ID_TABLE.SUB_ID, MAIN_TABLE.codeNew, MAIN_TABLE.Code, SUB_TABLE.Code  
    from (
        select SUBSTRING(CODE, 1, 6) + SUBSTRING(CODE, 9, 3) as CodeNew, Code
        from MAIN_TABLE
    ) as MAIN_TABLE
    inner join SUB_TABLE on MAIN_TABLE.CodeNew = SUB_TABLE.Code
    inner join ID_TABLE on ID_TABLE.SUB_ID = SUB_TABLE.SUB_ID
) Final
where MAIN_TABLE.code = Final.Code
```